# Dynamic positioning of text in a SVG

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I'm wondering if there is a way you can dynamically calculate the position of text in a SVG.

`Problem` I've two types of scales - Primary (only 1) and Secondary (1+).

- Primary Scale takes the left most place in graph
- Secondary Scale should be positioned next to the previous scale (either Primary or Secondary)
- Secondary Scale have only two values (Min and Max) so they should be visible relative to top and bottom of Primary Scale.

I know, this can be worked by providing hard coded X and Y coordinates of SVG `text` but is it possible by manipulating CSS e.g. using Position or Display or maybe Float property?

[image: Value Scales]

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 300 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="value-scales">
      <g class="primary-scale">
        <text x="5" y="20" fill="deepPink">2</text>
        <text x="5" y="40" fill="deepPink">4</text>
        <text x="5" y="60" fill="deepPink">6</text>
       </g>
      <g class="secondary-scale">
        <text x="20" y="20" fill="red">100</text>
        <text x="20" y="60" fill="red">200</text>
      </g>
      <g class="secondary-scale">
        <text x="50" y="20" fill="blue">40</text>
        <text x="50" y="60" fill="blue">160</text>
      </g>
</svg>
```

CodePen: [Dyanmic Scale Positioning](http://codepen.io/rohitkandhal/pen/zaLBp)

Comment: It's not clear, from your question, what you are asking.  How exactly are you trying to position your text?  The stuff about primary and secondary scales is confusing.  To me at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the numbers `40` and `160` in example above, use `text-align="right"` and measure from the right column of each cell.

For javascript coding, use `getBBox()` to obtain the bounding box and from there adjust the SVG text `x` and `y` values, assuming you don't use `text-align` properly

CSS manipulation would not be practical here since you may need a CSS for every cell.